# Use a stored procedure to search for a string

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, named-parameters

How can I pass paramenter into a stored procedure and use it to search the database?

I am trying to search the database for a business name which has the search term within it.

The following SP can be used to return all results:

```
BEGIN

SELECT company.businessname
FROM company;

END
```

Returns this result:

```
Better Cats Vetinary Practice
Appliance R'Us
The Beautiful Flower Company
Lovely Trips Away
```

However, if I use the 'searchtext' parameter which is passed in like this, and that parament is given the value of 'appliance' it should return one result, but returns nothing:

```
BEGIN

SELECT company.businessname
FROM company
WHERE company.businessname LIKE searchtext;
END
```

How can I get it to return the one result with 'appliance' in the business name?

Comment: you have to use `%` signs in Like: `'%'+searchtext+'%'`

Comment: But in MySQL, use [CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) for string concatenation, not `+` (that's Microsoft SQL Server syntax).

Comment: @Jens - that makes sense, but I have now changed it to this, SELECT company.businessname
    FROM company
    WHERE company.businessname LIKE '%'+searchtext+'%'; and it still returns zero records :-(

Comment: And if you use `lower(company.businessname)`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this appears to be to put the pass the named parameter including the %...eg searchtext = %appliance%, then the SP becomes:

```
SELECT company.businessname
FROM company
WHERE company.businessname like searchtext;
```

Then it returns the result expect.ed

Comment: Or you do what Bill explained to you in a comment and use `concat()` instead of `+` to combine strings.